# MaxMind - Convert binary DB into CSV in PHP

Tags: php, csv, binary, maxmind

I have MaxMind Country DB in binary format. The API I am using doesn't have any method to get all records. I can use the following code to get country data against single IP:

```
$reader = new Reader('/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIP2-Country.mmdb');
$record = $reader->country('210.56.18.71');
```

But I have to convert whole binary DB into a CSV file.

Is there any API available for that?

Comment: I made a utility https://github.com/knoguchi/mmdb2csv.  You can convert mmdb to csv, and load it from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the database in CSV.